# Javascript closure: Phonegap and 'this' in callback

Tags: javascript, cordova

I somehow need to pass a reference to my current object in a callback to phonegap's notification plugin. I'm pretty sure it involves closures but can't quite work it out.

Here's my code:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({ 
...
  delete: function(buttonIndex) {
    if (buttonIndex === 1) {
      // how to access 'this' here? 'self' doesn't work here either.
      console.log('Deleting survey with ID=' + this.get('obj_to_delete'));
    }
  },

  actions: {
    deleteAction: function(obj_id) {
    var self = this;

    this.set('obj_to_delete', obj_id);
    this.store.find('survey', obj_id).then(function(survey) {
       navigator.notification.confirm(
         'Are you sure you want to delete?', 
          self.delete,              // do i need some sort of closure binding self to this here?
          'Confirm delete',          
          ['Yes', 'No']         
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
});
```

How can I get a reference to 'this' in my delete method?

Comment: @bergi what exactly is relevant in that linked answer?

Comment: Everything, especially the last paragraph of Felix' answer.

Comment: got it thanks. i was in too much of a hurry :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

`navigator.notification.confirm(
     'Are you sure you want to delete?', 
      self.delete.bind(self),      // do i need some sort of closure binding self to this here?
      'Confirm delete',

      ['Yes', 'No']

    );`

in the line "self.delete.bind(self)", we bind this to the function "this.delete".

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. I'll look more into this to see if I can make it work.

Comment: OK this works if I then use 'this' in the 'delete' method. Thanks.